# Can't call Global.asax function

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have a pretty simple: global.asax file:

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>
<script runat="server"> 
static class MyClass
{
   static string MyFunction()
   {
      return("Test ok!");
   }
}
</script>
```

But when I try to call it from a web page....

```
<% Response.Write(MyClass.MyFunction());  %>
```

...I get "Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'MyClass' does not exist in the current context".

What am I doing wrong?

(Note: To make things more difficult, I'm calling this code from c# in an .asp page. To preserve links I mapped the aspx to the asp suffix. And that seems to work for regular c# code in my asp page.)

Comment: Why not simply add another C# file in the App_Code folder, add the `MyClass` class and call it there? The `Global.asax` is not meant for usage like this, imho.

Comment: I'm a complete newbee to aspx/c# and was just looking for a place to store my global utility functions. Global.asax looked good for this. But your way worked immediately, and if it's the recommend way, I'll do this way. Thanks. (I'll leave the question open nevertheless.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call the funcation using following code

```
<% Response.Write(ASP.Global_asax.MyClass.MyFunction());  %>
```

Comment: Tested it, but I got:  "CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Global_asax' does not exist in the namespace 'ASP' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

Comment: that worked in my application. just try to write it in code behind .

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbie in aspx/c# and don't know what "code behind" is.

Comment: its the .vb file or .cs file . just right click the page. and go to view code. in page load write the sentence

Comment: Couldn't get the code-behind thing to work, at all, sorry. Context-Menu doesn't mention anything of it and the samples on the internet have includes, classes, members, etc. where all I want is one "print". :( I'll stick with Maarten's solution because I got that one to work. But since your answer probably best answers the original question (and it's probably my fault that I couldn't get this to work), I'll mark it as answer. Thanks!